# Google Cloud AI Platform: I can't create a model version using the "--accelerator" parameter

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ai

In order to get online predictions, I'm creating a model version on the ai-platform. It works fine unless I want to use the --accelerator parameter.

Here is the command that works:

```
    gcloud alpha ai-platform versions create [...] --model [...] --origin=[...] --python-version=3.5 --runtime-version=1.14 --package-uris=[...] --machine-type=mls1-c4-m4 --prediction-class=[...]
```

Here is the parameter that makes it not work:

```
    --accelerator=^:^count=1:type=nvidia-tesla-k80
```

This is the error message I get:

```
    ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.ai-platform.versions.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

I expect it to work, since 1) the parameter exists and uses these two keys (count and type), 2) I use the correct syntax for the parameter, any other syntaxes would return a syntax error, and 3) the "nvidia-tesla-k80" value exists (it is described in --help) and is available in the region in which the model is deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using a recent version of the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-US-all-en-dr-skws-all-all-trial-b-dr-1008076&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_79747450687-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7C%20US%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20BMM%20~%20Cloud%20SDK-KWID_43700007037793881-kwd-26018927532&utm_term=KW_%2Bcloud%20%2Bsdk-ST_%2Bcloud%20%2Bsdk&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu6fzBRC6ARIsAJUwa2QfDqqWGmpBf2dQMbLkGEAWGDSunVfDzWx6H8jASSgpVSBAn1aIdZQaAlW6EALw_wcB).

Then you can use the following command:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME \
  --model $MODEL_NAME \
  --origin gs://$MODEL_DIRECTORY_URI \
  --runtime-version 1.15 \
  --python-version 3.7 \
  --framework tensorflow \
  --machine-type n1-standard-4 \
  --accelerator count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-t4
```

For reference you can enable logging during model creation:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform models create {MODEL_NAME} \
 --regions {REGION} 
 --enable-logging \
 --enable-console-logging
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for the --accelerator parameter as you can check in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/ai-platform/versions/create#--accelerator) is:

```
--accelerator=count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-k80
```

I think that might cause your issue, let me know.